# Showing two statements regarding bases in a topology are equivalent

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that the following two statements are equivalent -

**B1)** For each pair $B_1, B_2 \in \beta$ and each $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, there is $B_3 \in \beta$ such that $x \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2.$

**B2)** For each pair $B_1, B_2 \in \beta$ we have $B_1 \cap B_2 = \bigcup_{i \in I}B_i$, for some $B_i \in \beta, i \in I$.

From statement B1), we have that $\forall x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ there exists $B_x$ such that $x \in B_x \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$

$\implies B_1 \cap B2 \subseteq \bigcup_{x \in B1 \cap B2}B_x \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$

$\implies B_1 \cap B_2 = \bigcup_{x \in B1 \cap B2}B_x$

I.e. $\implies B_1 \cap B_2 = \bigcup_{i \in I}B_i$, for some $B_i \in \beta$, $i \in I$.

I haven't much experience of topology yet so I just wanted to check that this looks ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good. I would add a bit more details, though

$$B_1\cap B_2=\bigcup\{\{x\}\mid x\in B_1\cap B_2\}\subseteq
\bigcup\{B_x\mid x\in B_1\cap B_2\}⊆B_1\cap B_2$$
Therefore $B_1\cap B_2=\bigcup_{x\in I}B_x$ with $I=B_1\cap B_2$.